# How to set Custom List permissions in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, permissions, intranet

I have created a new Intranet for our IT department, with an issue reporting list. Every employee can submit an issue with their hardware/software there with some additional info and we can then mark it as being solved or in progress.

That's easy, I have set that up, but I need to set the permissions so that every person only sees their own submissions and not the submissions of other employees.

We often comment on the issues directly on the list, but if it were to stay like this, everyone could see our comments, that could potentially contain sensitive data, like temporary passwords or whatever.

How do I setup a specific permission like that? I haven't found a solution while creating my own permission, so I figure it isn't as easy.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Depends on your need. You may create a separated list for each employee. Let each employee update their own list. You then create a view to assemble all lists for management's overview.

Answer (score 1):

Please set the item-level Permissions via list settings>Advanced settings:

[image]